# font-family doesn't work in html

Tags: html, css

My style.css is below.

```
    body {
         font-family:'Gungsuh', sans-serif;
         font-weight:400px;
         -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
         font-size:14px;
         color:#888;
         }
       table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
       border-spacing: 0;
       }
```

But my website is with  "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
Why do I have the error?
Please help me..

Comment: have you included the @font-face as I don't think Gungsuh is a standard font

Comment: The error might be caused by the fact that you have single quotes rather than double. If not, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp might help with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've imported the font you are going to use?

There's another error. Font weight doesn't want px, just use font-weight:400;

EDIT:

You have to download your font in 4 different types for let it work on every device:eot,woof,woof2,ttf.

You have to include in your CSS this code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: '**YourFontWoopie**';
  src: url('webfont.eot');
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
}
```

Change webfont with the name of the font you've downloaded.
Once you've do that every time you wanna use the font just type:

```
p{
font-family:**YourFontWoopie**;
}
```

Comment: I want to use Hiragino Kaku Gothic.What should I do?

Comment: Sorry. What you mean is that I should change my code to @font-face {
  font-family: '**Gungsuh**';
  src: url('Gungsuh.eot');
  src: url('Gungsuh.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('Gungsuh.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('Gungsuh.woff') format('woff'),
  url('Gungsuh.ttf')  format('truetype'),
}
body {
  font-family:"Gungsuh";}    , right?

Comment: Yep but before you've to download all these files and put into the directory of you website. After that you should put in the src: url(**THELINKOFTHEFILE**)